# VisualSvn Server Error: User \ascii characters\ not found: /svn/MyProject

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server

I took a look at Windows "Event Viewer" and found many of these errors:

```
user \x90^\x9c\x02H\x90\xa0\XXX\XXX\XXX\XXX\XXX\ not found: /svn/MyProject
[client 95.226.XXX.XXX]
```

*(XXX for hide sensitive information)*

Visual Svn Server works properly!

What are these errors?

Visual Svn Server 3.2 (https) x64 on Winwows Server 2008 x64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error event means that there was an authentication attempt under username "\x90^\x9c\x02H\x90\xa0\XXX\XXX\XXX\XXX\XXX\" and such user does not exist (the username contains non-ASCII characters, therefore you see it garbled in the log. Garbled non-ASCII characters in the log is a known issue and is planned to be fixed).

Comment: the strange thing is that the errors come out with good authentications... The authentication works even when the errors appear.

Comment: @ar099968 if it is so, then I can suggest contacting VisualSVN support team at support@visualsvn.com